# How can I get this Python function to return a string instead of a list containing one string?

Tags: python, string

How can I get this Python function to return a string instead of a list containing one string?

```
def num_vowels(s):
    """ returns the number of vowels in the string s
        input: s is a string of 0 or more lowercase letters
    """
    if s == '':
        return 0
    else:
        num_in_rest = num_vowels(s[1:])
        if s[0] in 'aeiou':
            return 1 + num_in_rest
        else:
            return 0 + num_in_rest

#most vowels returns a list not a string
def most_vowels(wordlist):
    '''Takes a list of strings called wordlist and returns the string in
       the list with the most vowels.'''
    list_of_num_vowels = [num_vowels(x) for x in wordlist]
    max_val =  max(list_of_num_vowels)
    return [x for x in wordlist if num_vowels(x) == max_val]
```

Some test cases:

```
most_vowels(['vowels', 'are', 'amazing', 'things'])
```

output: `'amazing'`

```
most_vowels(['obama', 'bush', 'clinton'])
```

output: `'obama'`

Thanks!

Comment: please use the code formatting by indenting a line by four spaces for better readability

Comment: Thanks for who editted the formatting i'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Do the provided examples work?

Comment: `return list_with_one_element[0]`

Comment: In my function they output ['amazing'] and ['obama'] when they should output how it is shown ('amazing' and 'obama').

Comment: add `[0]` at the end: `return [x for x in wordlist if num_vowels(x) == max_val][0]`

Comment: Have you done any research at all into how to access list elements? I'm sure that'll be part of whatever instructional materials you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `most_vowels()` function is using a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to filter out matching values and return a new list. You could output the string directly in two ways.

The first way is to index the first result from the result of the comprehension.

```
return [x for x in wordlist if num_vowels(x) == max_val][0]
```

The other option, if you think you may get multiple results but still want a string, is to join any results with a comma (or other separator) into a string.

```
return ','.join([x for x in wordlist if num_vowels(x) == max_val])
```

This will convert `['first', 'second']` to `'first,second'`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks. :)

Comment: I upvoted and marked as correct. Why did my post get downvoted so hard? Trying to learn how to use the site sorry my formatting wasn't great.. people are jerks.

Comment: Don't get discouraged. Most likely it was a combination of the formatting and the fact that the answer is very basic python list indexing. People aren't being jerks, they just don't feel that it's a valuable question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer straight from [**`max`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) by comparing the number of vowels instead of the usual ordering for strings, by passing `num_vowels` as `key`:

```
def most_vowels(wordlist):
    return max(worldlist, key=num_vowels)
```

Alternatively, the way you've found the most number of vowels as `max_val` you could use [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a comprehension filter:

```
    return next(word for word in wordlist
                if num_vowels(word) == max_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `most_vowels` function sort of reinvents the wheel. Python already given you a much simpler facility for this this - using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with an optional `key` argument, and just picking the word with the most vowels outright:

```
def most_vowels(wordlist):
    return max(wordlist, key=num_vowels)
```